# Where did jsfiddle's various external libraries go?

Tags: jsfiddle

I used to be able to go to jsfiddle.net and load specific versions of jquery,angular,or whatever libraries I chose to use. But all that is gone now. Anyone know what happened? :O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jsfiddle.net's JavaScript block, on the upper right corner, you see the text "JAVASCRIPT" and a gear icon. Click on the gear icon and you should be able to select the needed library.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much! This change is *so* unintuitive, and there is no help (that I could find, and I looked many places). There is still an "External Resources" section on the left sidebar and the documentation is for an earlier version that made js libraries available from that sidebar, so it appeared as if this handy way to insert libraries had simply been removed. I wonder why they aren't helping users find the new location.

Comment: thanks for your response glad it helped you. but next time please add this as a comment (as opposed to being an answer).

Comment: I concur with your opinion that it's unintuitive, particularly as the original spot for the feature seems to still exist, so I don't see what they gained by moving it. I had to raise the same question myself (after failing to find this post). Fortunately someone directed me here. An overlap period during which it directs people from the old spot to the new spot might have been sensible. Meanwhile I'm still curious about that apparently non-functional bit to the left.