# JSFiddle appears to be broken

Tags: jsfiddle

I just opened jsfiddle. It seems that it's a new version which appears to have been nerfed. I can find no way to select to use jquery, or any other external for that matter.

The bar on the left that used to hold those options has a title, "External Resources", but the section appears to be non-functional. There's an entry field in it which doesn't appear to do anything and there's a small "+" button which also appears to do nothing.

I typed "jquery" into the text field, half expecting it to produce a list of versions of jquery to pick from, but alas nothing happened. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and [found this earlier question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960262/where-did-jsfiddles-various-external-libraries-go) which points out that the JavaScript text and gear icon are a button which activate a popover to add the external libraries.